# How to get actual request execution time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stopwatch, asp.net-core-middleware

Given the following middleware:

```
public class RequestDurationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<RequestDurationMiddleware> _logger;

    public RequestDurationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<RequestDurationMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await _next.Invoke(context);
        watch.Stop();

        _logger.LogTrace("{duration}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Because of the pipeline, it occurs before the end of pipeline and logs different times:

```
WebApi.Middlewares.RequestDurationMiddleware 2018-01-10 15:00:16.372 -02:00 [Verbose]  382ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2018-01-10 15:00:16.374 -02:00 [Debug]  Connection id ""0HLAO9CRJUV0C"" completed keep alive response.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost 2018-01-10 15:00:16.391 -02:00 [Information]  "Request finished in 405.1196ms 400 application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

How can I capture the actual request execution time from WebHost (405.1196ms in the example) value in this case? I want to store this value in database or use it elsewhere.

Comment: You could add two middlewares, one at the start that knows the start time and one at the end that does the actual logging.

Comment: I might be wrong but that value might only be available after all middleware has completed (otherwise webhost can't know the request has completed) so at that point you can't really get it other than from logs...

Comment: @DavidG I don't think you need two middlewares. One middleware is enough to act at the begin and at the end of pipeline, depending on the order which it has been configured in startup.

Comment: @AlexPaven Actually, you're probably quite right about that, but I'll wait for any other ideas coming before getting into the same conclusion.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that a request can be queued on the threadpool before any of the middleware runs...so from the outside a request can take several seconds...but the middleware may record several ms :/

Comment: @Darragh I can't think why some application would need to enqueue requests in that way.

Comment: @natenho this is how kestral web server behaves. it enqueues incoming requests to the threadpool queue to be processed. if you're application is suffering from thread starvation for example, a request can be queued for several seconds before a threadpool thread become free to process the request.

Comment: @Darragh Sorry, I've read again and now I see. I think you meant "middleware may record only a few ms" so.. In this case.. You may need to fix the pool starvation.. is the only way to record the actual request time. We may agree that the actual truth is on the client side anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62723412/how-can-i-correctly-measure-asp-net-core-request-durations

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I thought this question was really interesting, so I looked into this for a bit to figure out how the WebHost is actually measuring and displaying that request time. Bottom line is: There is neither a good nor an easy nor a pretty way to get this information, and everything feels like a hack. But follow along if you’re still interested.

When the application is started, the `WebHostBuilder` constructs the `WebHost` which in turn creates the `HostingApplication`. That’s basically the root component that is responsible to respond to incoming requests. It is the component that will invoke the middleware pipeline when a request comes in.

It is *also* the component that will create [`HostingApplicationDiagnostics`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs) which allows to collect diagnostics about the request handling. At the beginning of the request, the `HostingApplication` will call `HostingApplicationDiagnostics.BeginRequest`, and at the end of the request, it will call `HostingApplicationDiagnostics.RequestEnd`.

Not that surprisingly, `HostingApplicationDiagnostics` is the thing that will measure the request duration and also log that message for the `WebHost` that you have been seeing. So this is the class that we have to inspect more closely to figure out how to get the information.

There are two things the diagnostics object uses to report diagnostics information: A logger, and a [`DiagnosticListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.diagnosticlistener).

### Diagnostic listener

The `DiagnosticListener` is an interesting thing: It is basically a general [event sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sink_(computing)) that you can just raise events on. And other objects can then subscribe to it to listen to these events. So this almost sounds perfect for our purpose!

The `DiagnosticListener` object that the `HostingApplicationDiagnostics` uses is passed on by the `WebHost` and it actually [gets resolved from dependency injection](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHost.cs#L122). Since it is [registered by the `WebHostBuilder` as a singleton](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L247), we can actually just resolve the listener from dependency injection and subscribe to its events. So let’s just do that in our `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // …

    // register our observer
    services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticObserver>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
    // we inject both the DiagnosticListener and our DiagnosticObserver here
    DiagnosticListener diagnosticListenerSource, DiagnosticObserver diagnosticObserver)
{
    // subscribe to the listener
    diagnosticListenerSource.Subscribe(diagnosticObserver);

    // …
}
```

That’s already enough to get our `DiagnosticObserver` running. Our observer needs to implement [`IObserver<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobserver-1). When an event occurs, we will get a key-value-pair where the key is an identifier for the event, and the value is a custom object that is passed by the `HostingApplicationDiagnostics`.

But before we implement our observer, we should actually look at what kind of events [`HostingApplicationDiagnostics`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs) actually raises.

*Unfortunately*, when the request ends, the event that is raised on the diagnostic lister just gets passed [the end timestamp](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs#L202), so we would also need to listen to the event that is raised [at the beginning](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs#L190) of the request to read the start timestamp. But that would introduce state into our observer which is something we want to avoid here. In addition, the actual event name constants are [prefixed with `Deprecated`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs#L21) which might be an indicator that we should avoid using these.

The preferred way is to use [activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity) which are also closely related to the diagnostic observer. Activities are apparently states that track, well, activities as they appear in the application. They are started and stopped at some point, and also already record how long they run on their own. So we can just make our observer listen to the stop event for the activity to get notified when its done:

```
public class DiagnosticObserver : IObserver<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    private readonly ILogger<DiagnosticObserver> _logger;
    public DiagnosticObserver(ILogger<DiagnosticObserver> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnCompleted() { }
    public void OnError(Exception error) { }

    public void OnNext(KeyValuePair<string, object> value)
    {
        if (value.Key == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HttpRequestIn.Stop")
        {
            var httpContext = value.Value.GetType().GetProperty("HttpContext")?.GetValue(value.Value) as HttpContext;
            var activity = Activity.Current;

            _logger.LogWarning("Request ended for {RequestPath} in {Duration} ms",
                httpContext.Request.Path, activity.Duration.TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

*Unfortunately* there is just no solution without downsides… I found this solution to be very inaccurate for parallel requests (e.g. when opening a page that has also images or scripts which are requested in parallel). This is likely due to the fact that we are using a static `Activity.Current` to get the activity. However there does not really seem to be a way to get just the activity for a single request, e.g. from the key value pair that was passed.

So I went back and tried my original idea again, using those deprecated events. The way I understood it is btw. that they are just deprecated because using activities is recommended, not because they will be removed soon (of course we are working with implementation details and an internal class here, so these things could change at any time). To avoid problems with concurrency, we need to make sure we store the state inside of the HTTP context (instead of a class field):

```
private const string StartTimestampKey = "DiagnosticObserver_StartTimestamp";

public void OnNext(KeyValuePair<string, object> value)
{
    if (value.Key == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.BeginRequest")
    {
        var httpContext = (HttpContext)value.Value.GetType().GetProperty("httpContext").GetValue(value.Value);
        httpContext.Items[StartTimestampKey] = (long)value.Value.GetType().GetProperty("timestamp").GetValue(value.Value);
    }
    else if (value.Key == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.EndRequest")
    {
        var httpContext = (HttpContext)value.Value.GetType().GetProperty("httpContext").GetValue(value.Value);
        var endTimestamp = (long)value.Value.GetType().GetProperty("timestamp").GetValue(value.Value);
        var startTimestamp = (long)httpContext.Items[StartTimestampKey];

        var duration = new TimeSpan((long)((endTimestamp - startTimestamp) * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency));
        _logger.LogWarning("Request ended for {RequestPath} in {Duration} ms",
            httpContext.Request.Path, duration.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

When running this, we do actually get accurate results and we also have access to the HttpContext which we can use to identify the request. Of course, the overhead that’s involved here is very apparent: Reflection to access property values, having to store information in `HttpContext.Items`, the whole observer thing in general… that’s probably not a very performant way to do this.

*Futher reading on diagnostic source and activities: [DiagnosticSource Users Guid](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/2.0.0/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/DiagnosticSourceUsersGuide.md) and [Activity User Guide](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/2.0.0/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/ActivityUserGuide.md).*

### Logging

Somewhere above I mentioned that the `HostingApplicationDiagnostics` also reports the information to the logging facilities. Of course: This is what we are seeing in the console after all. And if we [look at the implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs#L172), we can see that this already calculates the proper duration here. And since this is structured logging, we could use this to grab that information.

So let’s attempt to write a custom logger that checks for [that exact state object](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingRequestFinishedLog.cs) and see what we can do:

```
public class RequestDurationLogger : ILogger, ILoggerProvider
{
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) => this;
    public void Dispose() { }
    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => NullDisposable.Instance;
    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true;

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (state.GetType().FullName == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingRequestFinishedLog" &&
            state is IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> values &&
            values.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key == "ElapsedMilliseconds").Value is double milliseconds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Request took {milliseconds} ms");
        }
    }

    private class NullDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        public static readonly NullDisposable Instance = new NullDisposable();
        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately (you probably love this word by now, right?), the state class `HostingRequestFinishedLog` is internal, so we cannot use it directly. So we have to use reflection to identify it. But we just need its name, then we can extract the value from the read-only list.

Now all we need to do is register that logger (provider) with the web host:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddProvider(new RequestDurationLogger());
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

And that’s actually all we need to be able to access the exact same information that the standard logging also has.

However, there are two problems: We don’t have a HttpContext here, so we cannot get information about which request this duration actually belongs to. And as you can see in the `HostingApplicationDiagnostics`, this logging call is actually only made when [the log level is at least `Information`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs#L176).

We could get the HttpContext by reading the private field `_httpContext` using reflection but there is just nothing we can do about the log level. And of course, the fact that we are creating a logger to grab information from *one specific* logging call is a super hack and probably not a good idea anyway.

### Conclusion

So, this is all terrible. There simply is no clean way to retrieve this information from the `HostingApplicationDiagnostics`. And we also have to keep in mind that the diagnostics stuff actually only runs when it’s enabled. And performance critical applications will likely disable it at one point or another. In any way, using this information for anything outside of diagnostics would be a bad idea since it’s just too fragile in general.

So what is the better solution? A solution that works outsid of a diagnostics context? *A simple middleware that runs early*; just like you have already used. Yes, this is likely not as accurate as it will leave out a few paths from the outer request handling pipeline but it will still be an *accurate measurement for the actual application code*. After all, if we wanted to measure framework performance, we would have to measure it from the outside anyway: as a client, making requests (just like the benchmarks work).

And btw. this is also how Stack Overflow’s own [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/) works. You just [register the middleware early](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNetCore) and that’s it.

Comment: **Unfortunately**, I have checked `HostingApplicationDiagnostics` source, but haven't gone that far ;-) I'll keep the early middleware approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62723412/how-can-i-correctly-measure-asp-net-core-request-durations

Comment: Hi Ian Kemp and poke,
Why Activity.Current is inaccurate in parallel situation?
Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity.current?view=net-6.0#system-diagnostics-activity-current
it said "The current operation for the current thread."
So, although it is static, but it is ThreadStatic, right? Then, each request should have its own Activity.Current which calculate its own duration. So, it should be a best way.

I haven't tried it, but could you help to correct me if I got something wrong?
Thanks,