# How can I correctly measure ASP.NET Core request durations?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Given the following most basic of ASP.NET Core applications (note the Thread.Sleep):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.Configure(appBuilder =>
                    appBuilder.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Finished in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds.");
                    }));
            });
}
```

And the following appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics" : "Information",
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

If I run an even moderate load test (100 requests, using bombardier in my case) I see latency of around 5 seconds.

```
~/go/bin/bombardier http://localhost:5000 -l -n 100 -t 60s
Bombarding http://localhost:51568 with 100 request(s) using 125 connection(s)
 100 / 100 [=================================================================================================================================] 100.00% 16/s 6s
Done!
Statistics        Avg      Stdev        Max
  Reqs/sec        19.46     250.28    4086.58
  Latency         5.21s   366.21ms      6.05s
  Latency Distribution
     50%      5.05s
     75%      5.05s
     90%      6.04s
     95%      6.05s
     99%      6.05s
  HTTP codes:
    1xx - 0, 2xx - 100, 3xx - 0, 4xx - 0, 5xx - 0
    others - 0
  Throughput:     3.31KB/s
```

However, all I see in the logs are

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2] Request finished in
> 1003.3658ms 200

Clearly the requests are taking more than 1 second. I believe the unaccounted 4 seconds are when the request is queued on the ThreadPool.

So my question is how can I measure this latency from *inside* my application?

Comment: What happens if `await Task.Delay(1000)` is used instead?

Comment: In this case performance is fine. But I'm not trying to improve the performance. I'm trying to measure it 

Comment: Did you read this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/measuring-and-reporting-the-response-time-of-an-asp-net-core-api/

Comment: Yes, that article suffers from the same problem. It only starts the timer after the request has started processing, not including time it was queued.

Comment: Probably a bad solution but new relic is really great at doing stuff like this for you.  Register your application and it can monitor the amount of time a request is taking, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

I ran your application in my environment, and the ASP.NET logs very similar to yours:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1022.4689ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1004.1694ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1003.4582ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1004.3703ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1003.3915ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1004.3106ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1003.122ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1017.028ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1004.2742ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1006.5832ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1004.9214ms 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1012.4532ms 200
```

As for **bombardier**, I got below output:

```
bombardier-windows-amd64.exe http://localhost:5000 -l -n 100 -t 60s
Bombarding http://localhost:5000 with 100 request(s) using 125 connection(s)
 100 / 100 [==========================================================================================] 100.00% 11/s 8s
Done!
Statistics        Avg      Stdev        Max
  Reqs/sec        11.29      99.10    1303.09
  Latency         5.78s      1.42s      8.78s
  Latency Distribution
     50%      5.17s
     75%      7.79s
     90%      7.88s
     95%      8.24s
     99%      8.34s
  HTTP codes:
    1xx - 0, 2xx - 100, 3xx - 0, 4xx - 0, 5xx - 0
    others - 0
  Throughput:     2.27KB/s
```

And below is Chrome Dev tools network output:

[image]

Also I test it with cURL (note that I had to apply `echo [%date%, %time%]` second time after the curl command manually, better accuracy can be done by doing it in `.bat` file
but overall the output confirms that the request took ~ 1100 ms:

```
C:\curl\bin>echo [%date%, %time%] && curl http://localhost:5000/
[Sun 07/12/2020, 13:12:35.61]
Finished in 1001 milliseconds.
C:\curl\bin\>echo [%date%, %time%]
[Sun 07/12/2020, 13:12:37.45]
```

So based on all above, it seems that `bombardier` output differ than what other tools reports, hence we might misunderstood the meaning of its output `latency`! I made little change to the command by letting it handle the 100 requests using 10 connections only instead of default 125 connections, and the output was:

```
bombardier-windows-amd64.exe -c10 http://localhost:5000 -l -n 100 -t 60s
Bombarding http://localhost:5000 with 100 request(s) using 10 connection(s)
 100 / 100 [==========================================================================================] 100.00% 8/s 11s
Done!
Statistics        Avg      Stdev        Max
  Reqs/sec         9.07      26.73     211.08
  Latency         1.06s   179.57ms      2.04s
  Latency Distribution
     50%      1.01s
     75%      1.02s
     90%      1.07s
     95%      1.19s
     99%      1.86s
  HTTP codes:
    1xx - 0, 2xx - 100, 3xx - 0, 4xx - 0, 5xx - 0
    others - 0
  Throughput:     1.79KB/s
```

Based on all above, I confirm that the single request taking ~ 1 second. as for bulk requests benchmarks, please try `Postman` otherwise we need to dig deeper to understand what`bombardier` Latency means exactly and how its calculated.

**Update**
I made small console tool that fire `HttpClient` in Bulk and it confirms the ~ 1 second response time, also I tried two benchmarking tools from [awesome-http-benchmark](https://github.com/denji/awesome-http-benchmark):

```
baton.exe -u http://localhost:5000 -c 10 -r 100
Configuring to send GET requests to: http://localhost:5000
Generating the requests...
Finished generating the requests
Sending the requests to the server...
Finished sending the requests
Processing the results...


====================== Results ======================
Total requests:                                   100
Time taken to complete requests:          10.2670832s
Requests per second:                               10
===================== Breakdown =====================
Number of connection errors:                        0
Number of 1xx responses:                            0
Number of 2xx responses:                          100
Number of 3xx responses:                            0
Number of 4xx responses:                            0
Number of 5xx responses:                            0
=====================================================


cassowary run -u http://localhost:5000 -c 10 -n 100

Starting Load Test with 100 requests using 10 concurrent users

 100% |████████████████████████████████████████| [10s:0s]            10.2299727s


 TCP Connect.....................: Avg/mean=1.90ms      Median=2.00ms   p(95)=2.00ms
 Server Processing...............: Avg/mean=1014.94ms   Median=1008.00ms        p(95)=1093.00ms
 Content Transfer................: Avg/mean=0.17ms      Median=0.00ms   p(95)=1.00ms

Summary:
 Total Req.......................: 100
 Failed Req......................: 0
 DNS Lookup......................: 5.00ms
 Req/s...........................: 9.78
```

Finally I used `nginx` on port 2020 as rev proxy in front of `kestrel` to see `bombardier` output:

```
bombardier-windows-amd64.exe  http://localhost:2020 -l -n 100 -t 60s
Bombarding http://localhost:2020 with 100 request(s) using 125 connection(s)
 100 / 100 [==========================================================================================] 100.00% 9/s 10s
Done!
Statistics        Avg      Stdev        Max
  Reqs/sec        11.76     128.07    2002.66
  Latency         9.08s   761.43ms     10.04s
  Latency Distribution
     50%      9.06s
     75%      9.07s
     90%      9.07s
     95%     10.02s
     99%     10.04s
  HTTP codes:
    1xx - 0, 2xx - 95, 3xx - 0, 4xx - 0, 5xx - 5
    others - 0
  Throughput:     2.51KB/s
```

As you can see, even with `nginx` it shows 9 seconds latency! that's should conclude an issue with `Bombarding` latency definition/calcs.

Below is nginx config:

```
server {
        listen       2020;
        location  / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
            proxy_set_header Host      $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
```

**Bonus**
If you want to hack the performance of `thread.sleep` to be similar as `await Task.Delay` then change `Main` to:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(130, 130);//Don't Use in Production.
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. However, in your tests, you're not putting the web app under enough load when you use only 10 connections because this throttles the requests. I am fully aware of what is causing the latency....it's thread starvation. All I want to know is how I can time this. There is an on-going discussion here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/23664

Comment: Not all the tests I used 10 connections! the `nginx` test was done the default 125 connections. about thread starvation its clear and agreed. In your questions you stated that the request taking more than 1 second...well my investigation shows its not. the extra 4 seconds or 8 seconds in `nginx` case, caused by something outside the web server life cycle. and that something is threads management in .Net core and OS.