# Create a Middleware to Set the Response Time

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-6.0

I create a middleware to stop every request in my WebAPI, but i want to set the Response Time in the Headers.

Example without the middleware:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        watcher.Stop();
        HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("x-response-time", watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        return Ok(new { message = "Success" });
    }
```

Then I create the middleware:

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        await _next(httpContext);
        watch.Stop();
        httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("x-time", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    }
```

But the result is not the expect, because i can't change the context after the calling to the _next.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get actual request execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192756/how-to-get-actual-request-execution-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HttpResponse.OnStarting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.onstarting?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method which:

> Adds a delegate to be invoked just before response headers will be sent to the client. Callbacks registered here run in reverse order.

Something along this lines:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    httpContext.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        watch.Stop();
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("x-time", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
    await _next(httpContext);
    watch.Stop();
}
```